# Split mp3 file into chuncks using multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, file, split, java-threads

I have to write a program which can split and merge files with various extensions. While splitting and merging it should use multiple threads. My code can do only a half of the task - if I don't use multithreading, it splits the file perfectly. If I do use multithreading, it splits the file, but saves only the first part several times.
What should I fix to make it work?

A method of **Splitter.class**

```
public void splitFile(CustomFile customFile, int dataSize) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= partsNumber; i++) {
        FileSplitterThread thread = new FileSplitterThread(customFile, i, dataSize);
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Run method of my **thread**:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(initialFile.getData());
        byte[] b = new byte[dataSize];
        String fileName = initialFile.getName() + "_part_" + index + "." + initialFile.getExtension();
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        int i = fileInputStream.read(b);
        fileOutputStream.write(b, 0, i);
        fileOutputStream.close();
        fileOutputStream = null;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to tell your threads which indexes each thread should work on. They should also share the byte array, so each thread don't have to read the whole time.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you cannot achieve multi-threaded file splitting with just InputStream. And you are reading the file from the beginning always, you are getting the same bytes

For a simple file splitting mechanism, the following could be the general steps:

1. Get the size of the file (data size)
2. Chunk it into offsets for each thread to read. Example, if you have 2 threads and the data is 1000 bytes, the offsets will be 0,1000/2, where the read length is 500. the first thread will read position from 0 to 499, the next thread will start at 500 and read till 999
3. Get two InputStreams and position them using Channel (here is a good post, [Java how to read part of file from specified position of bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35745403/java-how-to-read-part-of-file-from-specified-position-of-bytes))
4. Encapsulate the above info: InputStream, offset, length to read, output file name etc. and provide it to each of the threads